# Latin Modern main font with bold small capitals from CMU Serif

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I want to use bold small capitals from CMU Serif while setting Latin Modern as my main font.

*Minimal working example*

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman 10 Regular}[
    BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = {CMU Serif Bold}},
    SmallCapsFont = Latin Modern Roman Caps]

\begin{document}

Roman. \textbf{Bold.} \textsc{Small capitals.} 
\textbf{\textsc{Bold small capitals.}}

\end{document}
```

*Output*

[image: Output]

*Errors*

[image: Errors]

How can I resolve these errors? Bold small capitals from CMU Serif work fine when I'm not using `fontspec`.

**Edit.**  Maybe I can adapt [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font)? I know how to do import a symbol from `mathabx` but not from CMU Serif. I will just be using bold small capitals for heading numbers, so it doesn't matter if I have to define new symbols.

Comment: You might have a look at New Computer Modern.

Comment: Add `SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}`.

Answer (score 3):

As Ulrike Fischer said in her comment, you’re correctly selecting the small caps font but need to also select its small-caps feature.  You also need a few more lines to enable slanted small caps.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont = Latin Modern Roman Caps,
  UprightFeatures = {SmallCapsFeatures = {}}, % Suppresses warning about missing smcp feature.
  BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = {CMU Serif Bold}},
  ItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = {CMU Serif Roman Slanted}},
  BoldItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = {CMU Serif Bold Slanted}},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}]

\begin{document}
    Roman font. \textbf{Bold font.} 
    \textsc{Small caps font.} \textbf{\textsc{Bold small caps font.}}

    \itshape Italic font. \textbf{Bold font.} 
    \textsc{Small caps font.} \textbf{\textsc{Bold small caps font.}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern / CMU Serif sample]

You might also try New Computer Modern, which redesigned its small caps.

Comment: It didn't work for me. See update.

Comment: I will look at New Computer Modern.

Comment: @simplejack The warning you’re getting about Latin Modern Roman Caps lacking the `scmp` OpenType feature is harmless. You can, however, suppress it by moving the `SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}` option within the `BoldFeatures`, `ItalicFeatures` and `BoldItalicFeatures` blocks.

Comment: @simplejack I edited in a fix to suppress the warnings.

Comment: The issue is that the output doesn't have bold small caps ...

Comment: @simplejack It does on TeX Live 2020.

Comment: I'm using TeXShop so I don't see why it would be any different.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages about missing fonts in your `.log`?

Comment: The fienames (`cmunrm.otf` for CMU Serif, `cmunbx.otf` for CMU Bold Extended, `cmunbl.otf`, for CMU Unicode Bold Slanted, and `cmunsl.otf` for CMU Unicode Slanted) might work.

Comment: When I implement this solution, I find that `\textsl{...}` becomes identical to `\textit{...}`. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL Very few font families have separate `\itshape` and `\slshape` faces.

Comment: My question still isn't resolved... I gave it to you to say thanks for trying.

Comment: @simplejack Thank you. but I’m confused when you say you aren’t getting bold small caps. As you can see in the image, this does produce bold small caps and bold italic small caps for me, on TeX Live 2020. Are you using another TeX distribution?

Comment: @Davislor I'm not sure why it doesn't work or why I get that error message. I'm using MacTeX 2020.